# Creating a variable from existing strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, variables

i would like to create a variable using some existing data, lets say for example i have a dataframe

```
name age work_place
bill  32         IT
alex  20    Finance
```

and i want to take let say bill and make hisname+workplace into a new variable not knowing his name would be first so the var would look like
billIT = # some code

or make another dataframe with billIT as the dataframes name like

```
billIT = {'Name': 'Bill', 'Age': 32, 'work_place' : 'IT'}
```

Comment: `df.to_dict('r')[0]`?

Comment: maybe, I'll give it a try

Comment: i guess kinda like an fstring variable.. str(f"{df['Name'][i]}_df") = pd.DataFrame()